# How to export Drupal page as PDF?

Tags: files

I am using Drupal 7.17, and have created content of type book. I want the users to be able to export it to PDF format. The pages contains images, HTML tables, HTML ordered and unordered list (ul and li). What is the best way to do this? The content styles should be preserved when exported.

Comment: Did you try [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module?

Comment: Tell your users to install a PDF printer (like Primo PDF) or use Chrome which can already print to PDF...then just press print and it'll save as a pdf. Is there an angle to this question which makes it specifically related to Drupal and not to _any_ website?

Comment: indrock- i'll try it. Clive - it would be nice to have this feature in the site itself, rather than asking the users to install softwares.

Comment: @user12068 Fair point :) Be wary that server-side HTML -> PDF converters for PHP are notorious memory-hogs. Steer clear of anything that uses `DOMPDF` for complex layouts

Comment: It's also worth noting that most pdf generators have major issues with html tables that span over page breaks.

Comment: Clive, digital : thank you for your insights. I'll keep them in mind

Comment: If you do go the browser "Print to PDF" route, remember that you can add print specific stylesheets by referencing them in your theme info file (see [Writing theme .info files](http://drupal.org/node/171205) for instructions). I personally prefer this over the server-side PDF generation. I had to do server-side PDFs for a project which e-mailed the generated PDF to several users. It proved challenging… the PHP that generates the PDFs never seems to do exactly what you expect (unicode issues, styling issues, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Print module](http://drupal.org/project/print)

> This module allows you to generate the following printer-friendly
>   versions of any node:
>
> Printer-friendly version (webpage format) (at
>   www.example.com/print/nid) PDF version (at
>   www.example.com/printpdf/nid) Send by email (at
>   www.example.com/printmail/nid) where nid is the node id of content to
>   render.

And your choice of one of the 4 PDF libraries it supports. It does have very high memory requirements when generating PDF as previous comments have noted. It is [well documented](http://drupal.org/node/190171) and the PDF output is fully themeable.